# Using Rollup + Svelte with third party AMD libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, rollupjs, svelte

I understand that Svelte can produce AMD **output** and find some details on how to do this in the docs. I can also find some info on how to configure Rollup to **output** AMD modules. But what about **input**? What do I need to do when I have AMD modules as dependencies?

For example, suppose I have two different third party libraries that are both distributed as AMD libraries and I want to use those libraries in my Svelte project. How would I need to modify eg. [this nested components demo](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.29.1&example=nested-components) to allow these AMD modules to be used as dependencies in my Svelte components?

Also, am I able to configure whether I bundle these libraries together with my Svelte components? If so, where would I need to do that?

---

#### Note

I also raised this issue [on Github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/761).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AMD modules are a pain to convert to ES modules, so you may find it difficult to bundle them with Rollup. (There's [rollup-plugin-amd](https://github.com/piuccio/rollup-plugin-amd) but it comes with caveats.)

But you can easily treat them as external dependencies that get loaded separately — just `import` them as normal then configure Rollup:

```js
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  // ...
  format: 'amd',
  external: ['an-external-amd-module'],
  paths: {
    'an-external-amd-module': 'https://my-cdn.com/an-external-amd-module.js'
  }
};
```

You can see a demo [here](http://selective-tree.surge.sh/) ([repo here](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-amd-demo)) — note that we're loading an exernal AMD module called [the-answer](https://unpkg.com/the-answer), even though [it's a regular `import`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-amd-demo/blob/a5fe42f51bf904a0b467268a541e3b9b911ae3b7/src/App.html#L10), because of the [Rollup config](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svelte-amd-demo/blob/a5fe42f51bf904a0b467268a541e3b9b911ae3b7/rollup.config.js#L12-L16).

Comment: Thanks, again, for your swift response! This'll do for now.